# Bzr no working tree actual sources storage

Tags: version-control, dvcs, bazaar

A question I could not answer from the bazaar documentation. If I have a shared repository with branches having no working trees. So the branches folders only have a .bzr/ folder, not a single source code file or whatsoever I might be version controlling.

If I get this branch local using

```
bzr branch sharedrepository/somebranch localbranch
```

I get a branch with source code ! Where on earth are the sources stored on the sharedrepository side ? I looked inside .bzr but cannot find out.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.bzr` directory contains all the revisions in your repository. When you branch from that repository, by default it creates a branch with a working tree and checks out the latest revision into that working tree.

The revision data is packed and compressed inside the `.bzr` directory, you won't be able to find individual source files floating around inside there.

Comment: THX man ! I heard what I wanted to hear :)