# bzr branch doesn't download source files, only the branch information

Tags: bazaar, launchpad

I'm trying to download the source code for the project dhis2 by running "bzr branch lp:dhis2". This runs fine and says it branched a number of revisions, but it doesn't download any source code, only the repo information.

This seems to be a similar problem but it doesn't answer how I can actually get the source code..
[Bzr no working tree actual sources storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061993/bzr-no-working-tree-actual-sources-storage)

Any suggestions?

Comment: what does 'bzr info' say on the downloaded directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're having network issue while downloading over 800mb branch. Try to just checkout the branch:

```
bzr checkout lp:openobject-addons/7.0 --lightweight addons
```

I'm also having this problem in linux on AWS but had a success on my local PC.

Comment: I resolved this a long time ago but I'm gonna reply for a reference. I think you're right. I was tethering a 3G connection to my laptop in Rwanda at the time but re-downloading with a stable connection fixed it.